# How to add headers with ProxyKit

Tags: c#, .net-core

How can I add headers using ProxyKit?

This is the "proxy code" I have now:

```
app.UseWebSocketProxy(
    context => new Uri("ws://localhost:5005/"),
    options => options.AddXForwardedHeaders()
);
app.RunProxy(context => context
    .ForwardTo("http://localhost:5005/")
    .AddXForwardedHeaders()
    .Send()
);
```

This forwards the existing headers, but how do I add custom headers?

I would like to add a header that looks like this:
USER_NAME = user1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open braces for context

```
    app.RunProxy(context =>
    {
    //apply your headers to the context here
    
    context
         .ForwardTo(tunnelRedirectionOptions.HostUrl)
         .AddXForwardedHeaders()
         .Send();
     });
```